# Sorting arrays by their last argument

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy

I want to sort a numpy array of arrays based on their last entry.

For example, say we have this array of arrays:

```
a=np.array([np.array([1,2,5]),np.array([1,3,0]),np.array([1,4,-17])])
```

I want to return the array sorted this way:

```
np.array([np.array([1,4,-17]),np.array([1,3,0]) ,np.array([1,2,5]) ])
```

I.e. as -17 <= 0 <= 5, last array becomes the first one, and so on. Elements within each array must not be altered.

I suppose numpy has a builtin but I haven't been able to find it.

Comment: `a[a[:,-1].argsort()]`?

Comment: Is that as efficient as usual numpy operations?

Comment: What do you mean by `usual numpy operations`?